# What is wrong with my logic for finding square root by Newton's Method?

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I wrote the following code for finding square root by Newton's method by successive approximations but its not giving me the right answer.Can someone please explain it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define square(x) x*x
double rootByNewtonApprox(int n);
double improve(double n);
double average(double a,double b);
int goodEnough(double guess);
double guess(int n);
int number;
int main(void)
{

    double root;
    printf("\nEnter the number you want square root of: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    if(number<0)
            number = -1* number;
    root = rootByNewtonApprox(number);
    printf("\nThe square root of %d is %lf\n",number,root);
    return 0;
}
double guess(int n)
{
    return n/2;
}
double rootByNewtonApprox(int n)
{
    if(goodEnough(guess(n)))
            return guess(n);
    else
            rootByNewtonApprox(improve(guess(n)));
}

double improve(double guess)
{
    return average(guess,(number/guess));
}
double average(double a,double b)
{
    return ((a+b)/2);
}
int goodEnough(double guess)
{
    if(abs(square(guess) - number) <= 0.001)
            return 1;
    else
            return 0;
}
```

Now when I give `n = 2` it gives the ouput `nan` and when I give `n = 9` it tells `segmentation Fault`.

Comment: See @J.S. Taylor's answer below for the code. What you're running into is integer division (which disallows remainders) so some of your functions are not returning the correct floating point values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
double guess(int n)
{
    return  n / (double) 2;
}
```

Comment: Or dividing by 2.0 rather than 2.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot one `return`

```
double rootByNewtonApprox(int n)
{
if(goodEnough(guess(n)))
    return guess(n);
else
    return rootByNewtonApprox(improve(guess(n)));
    ^
}
```

Comment: sir,after making all the above said changes still no ouput just `segmentation Fault` is staring at my face!

Comment: I saw no reason to repeat what J.S. Taylor pointed out. So I added the reason to your second problem - `n=2` returns nan.